# svn checkout and debugging

Tags: maven, svn, ant

I have access to a project on SVN server and need to debug and understand the project. I exported the project as to ensure no changes affect the production or most recent updated version. But I cannot successfully run the ANT build as it looks for the jar files on the SVN server.

Can the project not run locally like this with my machine able to ping the server? I am familiar with MAVEN but not ANT so not sure if the checkout plays an important part in this.

Comment: Bad luck. Can you get whoever created this to help you build it locally? Can you get the jar files locally and change the ant script to use your local copies?

Comment: I could try and copy the jar files from the svn server location and try it and rebuild. But I would need to change the build script too. Not very helpful ppl around me but will try. So you saying it wont work exported; but what about checking it out? I could try it but just want to verify first. Not familiar with SVN

Comment: Practise it and read the red book - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/. You can revert any changes - don't panic.

Comment: Or you can create a branch from the current trunk and make tests on a developer branch..? (And yes please read the book as doctorlove already mentioned.)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is in version control, you can change things and see what happens.
For example, if you have the jar files in a different location, change the ant script and see if it works.

If you type

```
svn status
```

it tells you the status; `svn st` for short.

If you want to roll back

```
svn revert [filename]
```

will put the script back as it was.

You need to do a `svn commit` to send changes back to the server.

Don't be afraid to try things locally.

Comment: thank you. will give it a try and thanks for the link